# Can WebOptimizer pipeline be created in a separate file?

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-bundling, weboptimizer

I am working on a MVC project with .NET 6. I am using WebOptimizer for bundling and minification. The documentation mentions creating a bundling pipeline, like below.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddMvc();
    services.AddWebOptimizer(pipeline =>
    {
        pipeline.MinifyJsFiles("js/a.js", "js/b.js", "js/c.js");
    });
}
```

I want all the bundling rules/pipeline to reside in a separate class/file. And reference that class/file in `services.AddWebOptimizer()`
. This way Startup.cs is much more readabile and

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a static separate class like below:

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using WebOptimizer;
public static class WebOptimizerConfig
{
    public static void ConfigureBundles(IAssetPipeline pipeline)
    {
        pipeline.AddCssBundle("bundle.css", "/css/site.css", "/css/other.css");
        pipeline.MinifyJsFiles("js/a.js", "js/b.js", "js/c.js");

        //more bundling rules...
    }
}
```

Then reference this class like below:

```
services.AddWebOptimizer(pipeline =>
{
    WebOptimizerConfig.ConfigureBundles(pipeline);
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot !
Please take a look at this question as well
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77323851/disable-weboptimizer-bundling-for-debug-mode