# Disable WebOptimizer bundling for DEBUG mode

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, weboptimizer

I am migrating a .NET Framework project to .NET 6.

Old bundling logic in .NET framework had the below code:

```
#if DEBUG
   BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = false;
#else
   BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = true;
#endif
```

I believe, the code above disables bundling for DEBUG mode & enables it for RELEASE mode?

In .NET 6, I am using WebOptimizer for bundling.

Is there a similar option or setting in WebOptimizer as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So actually, this is not specific to .NET 6. I believe you may use something like this.

```
#if DEBUG
   // just do not add web optimizer code
#else
   app.UseWebOptimizer();
#endif
```

Also in documentation there is something like this:

Disabling minification:
If you want to disable minification (e.g. in development), the following overload for AddWebOptimizer() can be used:

```
if (env.IsDevelopment())
{
    services.AddWebOptimizer(minifyJavaScript:false,minifyCss:false);
}
```

https://github.com/ligershark/WebOptimizer

Regarding to your code in answer below, it is better to do like this:

```
public void Configure(WebApplication app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseWebOptimizer();
    }

    app.UseHsts();
    app.UseHttpsRedirection();

    app.Run();
}
```

Comment: I have posted the answer below, is that right? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think following will also mean the same.

```
public void Configure(WebApplication app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseHsts();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseWebOptimizer();
            app.Run();
}
```

Comment: I believe, you need to invert if statement and move app.UseWebOptimizer(); in it. Updating above.

Answer (score 0):

Given that you configure `AddWebbOptimizer` with a pipeline and that you are using the included taghelpers to "render" the bundle just change `EnableTagHelperBundling` appropriately like this:

```cs
#if DEBUG
   var useWebOptimizer = false;
#else
   var useWebOptimizer = true;
#endif

services.AddWebOptimizer(
    pipeline =>
    {
       pipeline.AddJavaScriptBundle("/bundles/js","/scripts/a.js","/scripts/b.js");             
       pipeline.AddCssBundle("/bundles/css","/scripts/a.css","/scripts/b.css");
    },
    option =>
    {
       option.EnableCaching = true;
       option.EnableTagHelperBundling = useWebOptimizer;
    });
```